# Retrieving the ExclusionFilter field of a TriggeredSendDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

Using the Python FuelSDK, I am able to ​*create*​ a TriggeredSendDefinition with an ExclusionFilter, as well as ​*update*​ an existing TriggeredSendDefinition's ExclusionFilter. This uses the prop `"ExclusionFilter"`, as documented here:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/triggered-sends/triggered-send-create.html.

What I CANNOT do, is ​*retrieve*​ the `"ExclusionFilter"` field from an existing TriggeredSendDefinition, as documented here:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/triggered-sends/triggered-send-retrieve.html (`"ExclusionFilter"` is not in the list).

**How can I retrieve the** `"ExclusionFilter"` **field from an existing TriggeredSendDefinition using the Python FuelSDK?**

(I CAN see in the Exacttarget dashboard that the Exclusion Script of the TriggeredSendDefinition is filled in after I make the Python FuelSDK API call to update the `"ExclusionFilter"` field, so I know that part works.)

Answer (score 0):

The ExclusionFilter is not current exposed as a retrievable property on the TriggeredSendDefinition object.